# «L'un des mes amis» ou « Un ami de moi » ?

Tags: grammaire, possessif

J'aimerais bien savoir laquelle de ces phrases est correcte ?

> Il est l'un des mes amis.
>
> Il est un ami de moi.

Answer (score 4):

*Il est l'un de mes amis* est **correct**, mais cette forme *il est ...* est peu employée.  (et non *des mes amis*)

*Il est un ami de moi* sonne très mal et devrait être évité, ainsi que toute forme un + substantif de moi en général, mais certaines fonctionnent, cela dépend du contexte.

**Mauvais emplois mais qui s'entendent, en étant très laids:**

> un frère de moi = un de mes frères, ou mon frère (s'il y en a
> plusieurs ou un).
>
> une femme de moi = ma femme. (une seule).
>
> un ami de moi = un de mes amis.

**formes acceptées, il y a peu de cas:**

*une idée de moi*, *une idée de lui* s'emploient en revanche, pour insister sur la provenance de l'idée.

Formes grammaticalement incorrectes, mais souvent utilisées à l'oral: *à* au lieu de *de* :

> une idée à moi, une assiette à moi, ...

Plutôt que *il est ...*, qui est plus littéraire, on emploie plus simplement *c'est ...*:

> C'est un de mes amis.
>
> C'est un ami. (sous-entendu: *un de mes amis*).

*C'est mon ami* n'a pas le même sens: il peut être le seul, et on insiste particulièrement sur lui.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax , effectivement, j'ai précisé. merci

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these sounds correct.

For your first attempt, I would probably say:

> Il est (l')un **de** mes amis.

I added the parentheses around the l' because, in my experience, it seems to be optional in both spoken and written French.

And for the second:

> Il est un ami **à** moi.

In any case, the easiest and most spoken way to say "He's my friend" would be

> C'est mon ami.

Comment: Yes, "_l'_" is optional and often used to ease the pronunciation when two vowel sounds are following each other.

Comment: Saying "Il est un amis à moi" is quite colloquial. It comes from "C'est à moi." or from the English use of "of mine". The first version is better, you can even enhance it by using "C'est un de mes amis" You can translate it quite closely : "Here/He is one of my friends."

Comment: "il est un ami à moi" n'est pas du français parlé correctement (et encore moins écrit).

Comment: "C'est un ami à moi" est une phrase que les enfants prononcent naturellement quand ils apprennent à parler, les parents s'empressent de corriger en « Il faut dire "C'est mon ami". »

Comment: Par hasard j'ai trouvé un exemple avec le pronom pers. [toi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/toi), donc un usage différent, mais intéressant : _Viens ici, que je te présente un ami... Un ami à toi, paraît-il..._ (Simenon).

Answer (score -1):

Les deux sont faux.

Il faudrait dire tout simplement:

> C'est mon ami

ou alors

> C'est un ami.

Comment: cela n'a pas le même sens: voir ma réponse.

Comment: Et la première phrase n'est pas gramaticalement fausse. elle sonne étrangement, mais c'est tout.

Comment: @LaurentS. Vu qu'il semble que le PO semble être un étranger qui apprend le français, c'est peu pertinant de dire si une phrase est gramaticalement juste ou non, mais c'est pertinant de lui apprendre a s'exprimer comme nous, sans que ses phrases aient l'air bizarres.

Comment: Savoir qu'une phrase, bien que correcte grammaticalement, n'est pas vraiment usitée, me semble être plus utile que croire qu'elle est incorrecte alors que ca n'est pas le cas. Dire que la première phrase est fausse est un mensonge.